# Is there a way to create a union types of String literals in Swift?

Tags: swift, union-types

In TypeScript, a programmer can define types with string literals. The type EventName below defines a type which must be either "start" OR "stop" OR "end". Note, this actually does not have an effect on runtime, which may be different from how types are used in Swift viz dynamic classes.

```js
type EventName = "start" | "stop" | "end";

interface Listenerlike {
    /** Bind a start event listener. */
    on(event : "start", listener : (startObj : StartObjectlike)=>void) : this;
    /** Bind a stop event listener. */
    on(event : "stop", listener : (startObj : StopObjectlike)=>void) : this;
    /** Bind an end event listener. */
    on(event : "end", listener : (startObj : EndObjectlike)=>void): this;
}
```

In Swift, I'm only aware of doing something similar with enums:

```swift
enum Event : String {
    start = "start",
    stop = "stop",
    end = "end"
}

protocol Listenerlike<T>{
    on(event : Event.start, ...);
    on(event : Event.stop, ...);
    on(event : Event.end, ...);
}
```

Is there a way to do a string literal union in Swift?

Comment: No. But why doesn't the enum accomplish exactly what the string literal union did? I don't get it. You solved your own problem so what's the question?

Comment: I just prefer the type union to the enum for code suggestions. That's all.

Comment: I still don't get it. Different languages are different. So?

Comment: Could you add some more explanation as to what the the TypeScript code is doing? The enum I get, but what is this interface definition mean? The parentheses aren't even balanced. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Alexander Added a note.

Comment: @LiamMonninger Could you double-check the parentheses?

Comment: @Alexander good catch.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the TS correctly, the Swift counterpart would just be a protocol with 3 functions:

```swift
protocol Listener {
    // FIXME: These parameter/type names are horrible
    func onStart(listener: (StartObject) -> Void) -> Self
    func onStop(listener: (StopObject) -> Void) -> Self
    func onEnd(listener: (EndObject) -> Void) -> Self
}
```

le fin.

Comment: Go it. Thought this might be better appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer to match your recent edits.

Answer (score -1):

No. There is not a way to create a String literal type union in Swift.

Comment: (Not my downvote) This is technically the answer to your immediate question as posted in the main post, but I think you should reframe it to be more like: "I wrote this code in TypeScript, what's the best way to map it onto Swift?". The two languages share some similarities, but they also have a lot of differences (for one, Swift leans much more heavily towards nominal types, whereas TypeScript tends to prefer structural typing), so you shouldn't expect the same program to be similar in both languages (if written idiomatically in both)

Comment: If you wan to write add that to your answer, I'll change my question and mark yours as accepted. Don't care about the downvote, this is a bit of a burner.

Comment: Which part exactly would you like me to add to my answer? In any case, I'd recommend you take my up on my suggestion to rebrand this question as "I wrote this code in TypeScript, what's the best way to map it onto Swift?". You'd likely get more answers and more useful help/advice overall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).